# How to populate dropdown with json data and send selected option to database using javasript and java?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, database, dropdown

I have used a URL where I have stored JSON data which is an array of different industries. I want to populate the 'industry' dropdown with JSON data and send the selected option to a database.I have added servlet code and database code below. In database, other feilds are getting stored in database but not industry feild. Can anyone help in solving this problem?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/anushikha700/jason/master/industries.json";
  $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(index, value) {
      // APPEND OR INSERT DATA TO SELECT ELEMENT.
      $('#sel1').append('<option value>' + value.name + '</option>');
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="../JobController?op=add" method="post" class="form-horizontal form-material">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-6">Industry</label>
    <label class="col-md-6">Title</label>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <select id="sel1" name="industry" class="form-control">
        <option value="">Select Industry</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <input type="text" name="title" placeholder=" Eg: Software Engineer" class="form-control form-control-line">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-12">Experience Required(in Years)</label>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <input type="number" name="exper_min" placeholder="Minimum" class="form-control form-control-line">
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <button class="btn btn-success" id="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

```
//JobContoller

 protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse 
response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
     PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    String op = request.getParameter("op");
    if (op != null && op.equals("add")) {
        String industry= request.getParameter("industry");
        String title= request.getParameter("title");

        int exper_min= 
 Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("exper_min"));

  HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        com.beans.Job job = (com.beans.Job) session.getAttribute("job");

        job.setIndustry(industry);
        job.setTitle(title);
       job.setExper_min(exper_min);

        com.daos.JobDao jd = new com.daos.JobDao();
        if (jd.add(job)) {
            session.removeAttribute("job");
            response.sendRedirect("view.jsp");

        }
    }

//JobDao

public boolean add(Job job)
    {
   boolean status=false;
   ConnectionPool cp = ConnectionPool.getInstance();
   cp.initialize();
   Connection con = cp.getConnection();
   if(con!=null) 
   {
       try{
           String sql= "Insert into 
       job(industry,title,exper_min)values(?,?,?)";
           PreparedStatement smt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
          smt.setString(1, job.getIndustry());
           smt.setString(2, job.getTitle());

          smt.setInt(3, job.getExper_min());

           if(smt.executeUpdate()>0)
           {
               status=true;

           }


           smt.close();
           cp.putConnection(con);

       }
       catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Database Error :"+ e.getMessage());
    }

   }
   return status;
  }
```

Comment: Well you've done the first part. What's the issue with the rest of it?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I want to send that selected option from dropdown to database. I dont know how to do that.

Comment: You've got a `form` element and `submit` button. This sends it to the `action` you've set in the form. You need to write the code in that location to save the data. That is the relevant part of the question which you need to show, not the JS or the HTML